# What are general areas you would want to use XMPP?

Tags: xmpp

I understand that XMPP is used in chat services, but it seems to be more generally useful than that. Can someone list some scenarios and examples where you would consider using XMPP, and the pros and cons of it versus other approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that Dropbox uses it for its filesharing system in Android (possibly it does in other platforms too).

Cons: much more verbose than binary (more bandwidth).

Pros: a wide variety of already implemented client and servers. A wide range of already implemented reliability, scalability, security, presence, rpc, federation, custom components, mail, VoIP mechanisms... the [list](http://xmpp.org/extensions/) is very very long. Even if you need something  different, and you know where to touch, you could extend it to your needs, inheriting all the already implemented features.

Comment: Interesting about Dropbox. Thanks for your response, Mrrtnn. I guess I was wondering in general about the use-cases for XMPP. I saw a lot of custom extensions, but when would you choose to use it and when not? The verbosity is a good point.

Comment: Do you have an example of a use case of the kind you mention? I don't understand your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We had a project on collecting information eg. wind direction, temperature, stock and forex, etc. Every sensor is a Jabber 'user'.

1. This allows us to detect if a sensor
   is online, offline or problematic.
2. Sensors also publish information to
   a pubsub node to be distributed to
   collectors.
3. Human users can also
   interact with a particular sensor by
   querying with the sensor. The sensor
   returns human friendly formatted
   data.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Chuk. I guess I was wondering in general what are the use-cases.

Answer (score 0):

We use it for chatrooms, and for distributing sports results to users watching live events.

Google Buzz and Facebook talk is built on it.